# How to iterate over inner class that extends List<Something>?

Tags: java

If you have the following as your inner class

```
private static final class LinkedListExtension extends LinkedList<String> {
    {
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");
    }
}
```

How can you iterate over `LinkedListExtension`'s content?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question shows no research effort. You didn't even try the most obvious suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as normal list:

```
LinkedListExtension myList = new LinkedListExtension();
for (String s : myList)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @KirkWoll `for( int i ... ){ s.get(i)...`, `for( Iterator<String> iter ... ){ iter.next()... ' `while` ... ;)

Comment: @trutheality, that's not what I meant.  I mean the question is silly -- of course you can interact with a subclass of a list exactly the same as a normal list.

Comment: @KirkWoll I know. I was being clever. [Humor!]

Answer (score 2):

```
LinkedListExtension  list = new LinkedListExtension();
for (String s : list) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedListExtension();
for (String str : list)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
Iterator i = new LinkedListExtension().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
}
```